# Sending ArrayList using Ksoap2

Tags: java, android, arraylist, ksoap2

I'm trying to send an arraylist which is an encoded string and getting

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [abc.docx, def.docx]**

This is how I'm converting it to byte array and passing it:

```
 public static String convertFileToByteArray(File f) {
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 11];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
            bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

        Log.e("Byte array", ">" + byteArray);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Adding it to ArrayList as shown:

```
ArrayList<String> encodedlist = new ArrayList<String>();
encodedString = convertFileToByteArray(mySelectedFile);
encodedlist.add(encodedDocument);
```

This is my code for sending it to server side:

```
 public static boolean invokeUploadMultipleDocuments(String RandomFolder, ArrayList FileNames, String webMethodName) {
    boolean UploadStatus = false;
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethodName);
    // Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo filenamePI = new PropertyInfo();

    // Set Filenames
    filenamePI.setName("FileNames");
    // Set Value
    filenamePI.setValue(FileNames);
    // Set dataType
    filenamePI.setType(ArrayList.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(filenamePI);

    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethodName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to  boolean variable variable
        UploadDocumentStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
        MainActivity.errored = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Return booleam to calling object
    return UploadStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON library dependency 
In  build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Then use below Code

```
List<List> encodedlist = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("one", "two","three"), 
                                       Arrays.asList("four", "five","six"));

String levelPatternGson = new Gson().toJson(encodedlist);
invokeUploadMultipleDocuments(levelPatternGson);
```

Now code for sending it to server side

```
public SoapObject invokeUploadMultipleDocuments(String levelPatternGson){ 
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethodName);
         SoapObject WebRq = new SoapObject("", "PropertyInfo");
         WebRq.addProperty("FileNames",FileNames);
         request.addSoapObject(WebRq);
         return request;
      }
```

NOTE:I didn't try myself but may be this way it will work.